# Low power design, choosing correct buck-boost converter for LiPo battery

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, design, buck-boost, lora

I want your opinion on subject considering low power applications. I want to build basic loraWan tracker with Murata Lora module(3V3), and I want to use LiPo battery. What Im struggling with is power design circuit. I want a dc/dc buck-boost converter which can work from very low voltage input(to use maximum from the battery) and very low power consumption. 
For now Im considering this IC(other suggestions welcomed):

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3106f.pdf

What do you think about it?
Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Looks like a good choice to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This converter will work but there are much less complex converters available if you dont need all the extras the IC you mentioned is offering. Its also depending on your converter output requirements or rather the input requirements of the circuitry you want to supply. Also there are ICs available with a much smaller footprint which i guess is a factor in a portable application. Consider for example [BD70522GUL](https://www.rohm.de/datasheet/BD70522GUL/bd70522gul-e) from rohm, which is more than 10 times smaller. Also Keep in mind that LiPo batteries are not very happy about getting discharged too low.

Comment: Well I dont plan on recharging it, just want to max it out as long as it can go. My output current should be around 50mA. Thats why Im considering LTC3106 IC, cause I want lowest possible input voltage to max out the battery, but also very low power consumption. Yet LTC3106 is expensive tho.. Thank you for your answer Jogitech.